Animations moved after setting them as Actions (Mixamo to Blender)
thanks for reading. I'm a beginner in Blender. I imported several animations from Mixamo (1 with skin, 3 without skin) and the animation looks good with the armatures.

Then I go to the Dope Sheet --> Action Editor, Then NonLinear Animation, push down the animations, and delete the armatures (except the skinned one). Then I add the new animations to the track but they all are moved and seem to depend on the hips.

How can I fix this so they behave like with the original armatures? I'm following this tutorial, just for reference. Any help is greatly appreciated!!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fLfjHzJy2A0&t=210s&ab_channel=MKGraphics

I noticed that the armature where I'm putting these actions is called "Hips". This might be the reason. But the I don't know why It's setup like that... What I'm trying now is working without that skin and only armatures and maybe import a model to attach them too...
Here are the project files! Thank you so much in advance!


Maybe simply edit the 2nd and third action and move the spine or root bone to the exact same location as in the first action? or please share your file so that we can test (only keep the armature)?

again please share your file so that we try it

Sorry @moonboots I uploaded the file now! It's my first time using the forum so I'm learning how to use the tools.

The root of the armature is probably the base of the spine, although most rigs have another bone with no deformation at the feet of the skeleton, with the spine base parented to it (disconnected). I recommend you do this in Mixamo if possible.

in the shared file I can see only one moving action, the other ones are still. That said i think that if you want to make all your actions match, change the location of the spine so that they match and keyframe

@TheLabCat Thanks, I will try this!

@moonboots hmm I wonder why the other actions are still... I think that what TheLabCat said regarding the base of the armature is the problem. I will see if I can make it the feet instead.
